# Reduce duplication of similar HTTP fetch methods for each model class

Tags: flutter, dart

I thought I've got this covered but it looks like I was wrong. Now I need to rework all my project but I'm not sure what is the best way (or common way) to do it. So far I've got API_service class with all possible calls to my back end like that

```
class APIService {
  Future<List<dynamic>> getByPost(
      {String path, Map<String, dynamic> body, String token}) async {
    try {
      final header =
          [APIHeader.authorization(token), APIHeader.json()].reduce(mergeMaps);
      final http.Response response =
          await http.post(path, headers: header, body: json.encode(body));
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw ServerException(jsonResponse["error"]);
      }
      return jsonResponse['result'];
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
 ...
}
```

and database class where I got all my request

```
class User extends Database with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;

  set token(String value) => _token = value;

  Future<SeriesModel> getSeries(int id) async {
    final response = await APIService()
        .getById(path: APIPath.series('get'), token: _token, id: id);
    return SeriesModel.fromJson(response);
  }
 ...
}
```

problem with this approach is that my database class is getting really big because I have to create new method for each call. For example if I want to get something foo by id I would have to create new method getFoo in my database class. I know this is not the best way to do it so I'm trying to find better approach. So what is a common way to structure and reusing http calls

Comment: What do you mean by _"new method for each call"_ ?

Comment: @easeccy basically from the code above I'm getting one SeriesModel from the database. If I want to get a different data then the call would be exactly the same only path and model would be different so I would have to create another method for that.. I already got about 30 methods in that class and I'm not even in the middle of my project. There must be a better way to do this.. I literally made this up from the top of my head which looked nice at the beginning but now it looks a bit silly. I think there is a common way to do it I just can't find it

Comment: Can you make your backend calls `{query: "user", id: "1234}` for user, `{query: "foo", id: "4567"}` for foo etc. ?

Comment: @easeccy  I don't think I understand what you trying to say.. I can do whatever I want and need in my backend. Each call however has different path and receive different data so in my front end I have to catch them or assign the into a different models but the principle is exactly the same. Therefore I'm trying to find to make these methods be more (in above example `getById`) reusable for different data and paths

Comment: If you have 30 different classes and you are fetching relevant data from backend, I think 30 methods is acceptable. If you want to reuse methods it highly depends on your models. And are you also complaining about initializing `APIService` class on each method too?

Comment: @easeccy API Services are ok.. I've got only methods there for posting getting putting and deleting so that is fine. the database class is what bothers me and trying to make it better.. My backend has database with 34 tables. I need to do all requests(post, get, delete, put) on each table. With this approach the database class in my front end will end up with 34*4 which is 136 methods which doesn't looks right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216920/discussion-between-easeccy-and-delmin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) to reduce duplicate code.

Here is a Dart example that can run on DartPad:

```
var database = {
  {"id": 1, "score": 555, "type": "user"},
  {"id": 2, "score": 777, "type": "user"},
  {
    "id": 3,
    "started": DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1592515515550),
    "type": "match"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "started": DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1593513315000),
    "type": "match"
  },
};

class User {
  int id;
  int score;
  User(this.id, this.score);
  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = data["id"],
        score = data["score"];
}

class Match {
  int id;
  DateTime started;
  Match(this.id, this.started);
  Match.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = data["id"],
        started = data["started"];
}

T getData<T>(int id, T Function(Map<String, dynamic>  decoded) creator ) {
  Map<String, dynamic> result = database
      .singleWhere((dynamic item) => item["id"] == id, orElse: () => null);
  
  // This is where the magic happens. The `creator` function we supplied by the argument
  // will create instace of T by using the 'result' as argument.
  return creator(result);
}

void main() {
  User _user = getData<User>(1, (data) => User.fromJson(data));
  Match _match = getData<Match>(4, (data) => Match.fromJson(data));

  print(_user.score);
  print(_match.started);
}
```

You can make `getData` async too. You are also initiating in `APIService` in every method, you can make it factory. Same thing goes with the HTTP client. Reduce the amount of unnecessary initiation of resources in your code.